# How to update a single value in Polars dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-polars, setvalue

In Pandas, you can update a value with the **[at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)** property, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6]})
df.at[2, "col2"] = 99

print(df)
# Output

   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3    99
```

What's the idiomatic way to do that in Polars?

Comment: `df[[2], "col2"] = 99`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use polars' [*square brackets indexing*](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/selecting_data/selecting_data_indexing.html#rules-for-square-bracket-indexing) :

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6]})
​
df[2, "col2"] = 99 #same syntax as pandas but without the `.at`
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)
​
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 5    │
│ 3    ┆ 99   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use when-then-otherwise:

```py
df.with_row_count().with_columns(
    col2=pl.when(pl.col("row_nr") == 2)
    .then(99)
    .otherwise(pl.col("col2"))
).drop("row_nr")
```

example:

```py
In [5]: df.with_row_count().with_columns(col2=pl.when(pl.col('row_nr')==2).then(99).otherwise(pl.col('col2'))).drop('row_nr')
Out[5]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 5    │
│ 3    ┆ 99   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

---

It does seem a bit verbose though, so I'm curious if other answers will suggest something simpler